# limit the amount of memory kube-controller-manager uses

Tags: kubernetes, out-of-memory, kube-controller-manager

running v1.10 and i notice that `kube-controller-manager`s memory usage spikes and the OOMs all the time. it wouldn't be so bad if the system didn't fall to a crawl before this happens tho.

i tried modifying `/etc/kubernetes/manifests/kube-controller-manager.yaml` to have a `resource.limits.memory=1Gi` but the kube-controller-manager pod never seems to want to come back up.

any other options?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in kube-controller-manager, and it's fixed in https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/65339

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you missed information about the amount of memory you use per node.

Second, what do you mean by "system didn't fall to a crawl" - do you mean nodes are swapping?

All Kubernetes masters and nodes are expected to have swap disabled - it's recommended by the Kubernetes community, as mentioned in the Kubernetes documentation.

Support for swap is non-trivial and degrades performance.

Turn off swap on every node by:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

Finally,

```
resource.limits.memory=1Gi
```

is [default](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-compute-resources-container/#meaning-of-memory) value per pod. These limits are hard limits. Pod reaching this level of allocated memory can cause OOM, even if you have gigabytes of unallocated memory.